# multiple jquery animations

Tags: jquery

I have 3 divs on my page that Im trying to give an appearance of expanding out using the jquery .animate width function. The thing is I dont want them all to expand at the same time but I also dont want them to only start when the one before it has finished. Im kinda needing them to start a few miliseconds after the previous once has started so there just slightly out of sync, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [DEMO link](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/NQnnU/1/)

```
$('.box').each(function(i){                          // 'i' = index
   var spd = 700;                                    // set speed (animation/delay) time
   var dly = spd*i;                                  // 700*0 = 0 ; 700*1 = 700 .....
   $(this).delay(dly).animate({width: 500 },spd);    // now you have proper delays.
});
```

---

**EDIT :**

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/NQnnU/2/)

```
$('.box').each(function(i){   
   var dly = 400*i;                                   // delay time is less than...
   $(this).delay(dly).animate({width: 200},800);     // the animation time
});
```

**And the whole in a couple of lines.**

Incredible that the above was '-1' after a **Q** edit **1h** after my first answer.
Never mind. In a couple of lines here's your script. 
By the way the above was so nicely explained that anyone could fix it in fiew seconds to get the best results. **The approach** was the key. Thanks! ;)

Comment: He states that he does not want the animations to occur after each other but rather at the same time. If you're going to complain about other peoples code at least make sure yours is right!

Comment: haha, yeah to be fair roXon, I did mean I didnt want the animations to happen at the same time nor wait for the previous one to finish before each animation started :P

Answer (score 3):

Try using `.delay()` before `animate()`:

`$('#mydiv').delay(200).animate`

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/yF8Vx/

Comment: Forgot about delay. Probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify not to queue an animation as one of the options:

```
$('div').animate({"width": 100});
```

Then you could run this code in seperate `window.setTimeout` calls to stagger the effect.

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/6Dqus/1/

Comment: I don't think you need to disable the queuing as the effects are on different elements. The timeout alone should suffice. Still +1 for taking the time to create a jsFiddle

Comment: You're right. Suppose that makes sense. Updated answer without the queue disable.

Comment: Hi rich, I was trying to use your method but when I set my width to 0px and expand it the layers seem to fall on top of each other on my website, I tested it on jsfiddle and it does the same thing when you give each div a "#" and their proper names i.e #div1 #div2 #div3

Comment: @RichardD is it possible to do this sort of effect but to each line of text rather then divs? like in this video http://iliketoplay.dk/#/blog/deff

Answer (score 0):

You could delay them with a simple timer:

```
// Start animation 1

setTimeout(function {
  // Start animation 2
}, 100);

setTimeout(function {
  // Start animation 3
}, 200);
```

Comment: Err... no. I'm pretty sure this works and answers the OP's question. If it doesn't work, please feel free to correct. Since there are only 2 divs to be delayed, using each() seems like overkill - this way removes dependence on the order of the elements and timings can be tweaked very easily without fiddling around with a formula. As per @Canuteson's answer, I would however use delay() instead of setTimeout() as it's a bit shorter. I'd completely forgotten about delay()

Answer (score 0):

Use `each()` width `delay()`:

```
$("divs").each(function(index){
    $("this").delay(index*200).animate({"width":100},500)
})
```

This will start next animation 200ms after *starting* previous one.

Fixed missing argument.